# jquery UI cascading autocomplete widget

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, combobox, autocomplete

I'm trying to build cascading auto-complete comboboxes.

http://jsfiddle.net/BurritoWhisperer/zbjk1ss1/3/

What I'd like to see if when I choose an item from the first select (id = "one"), I'd like to see the UI update for the second select (id = "two").

```
if (arg1 == "1") {
    $("#two").append($('<option selected></option>').val('1.1').html('1.1');

    $("#two").append($('<option></option>').val('1.2').html('1.2');
} else if (arg1 == "2") {
    $("#two").append($('<option selected></option>').val('2.1').html('2.1');

    $("#two").append($('<option></option>').val('2.2').html('2.2');
}
```

I can see the trigger happening, but the UI never updates.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

3 things are missing.

https://jsfiddle.net/mindlessbaby/zbjk1ss1/70/

1) wrap the combo box with ui-widget class

```
<div class="ui-widget">
<select id="one"></select>
<br/>
<select id="two"></select>
```

2)      `// added- inserted refresh function -BD
        refresh: function () {
            selected = this.element.children(":selected");
            this.input.val(selected.text());
        },`

3)    `// added- update second box value and refresh ui -BD
    $("#two").val("").combobox("refresh");`